# what is the most efficient way to search binary search tree?

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, binary-search

I have seen a lot of search algorithms to search in a binary sorted tree, but all of them are using the same way: recursion. I know recursion is expensive in comparison to loops, because every time we call the search function, a new stack frame is created for that method, which will eventually use a lot of memory if the binary search tree is too big.

Why can't we search the binary search tree like this:

```
while (root!=NULL)
{
    if (root->data==data)
        return 0;
    else if (data > root->data)
        root=root->right;
    else
        root=root->left;
}
```

I think that this way is faster and more efficient than the recursive way, correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: you should benchmark.

Comment: I don't need time to measure and compare I am just asking theoretically :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably your way -which is the common way to code that in *C*- might be faster, but you should benchmark, because some C compilers (e.g. recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) when invoked with `gcc -O2` ...) are able to optimize most [tail calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) as a jump (and passing values in registers). tail call optimization means that a [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) frame is reused by the callee (so the call stack stays bounded). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization).

FWIW, in OCaml (or Scheme, or Haskell, or most Common Lisp implementations) you would code a tail-recursive call and you know that the compiler is optimizing it as a jump.

Recursion is not always slower than loops (in particular for tail-calls). It is a matter of optimization by the compiler.

Read about [continuations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) and [continuation passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style). If you know only C, learn some functional language (Ocaml, Haskell, or Scheme with [SICP](http://mitpress.edu/sicp/) ...) where tail-calls are very often used. Read about [call/cc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-with-current-continuation) in Scheme.

Comment: so, as you have mentioned the stack will hold one frame for the whole recursion?! @Basile

Comment: @flashdisk: Yes, recursive calls in tail position do not allocate a new stack frame if the compiler does this optimization. As Basile said, most functional languages will mandate that the compiler always optimizes tail calls if possible while in C this is not guaranteed (so you should code iteratively if you want to be safe). BTW, if you have some extra time, check out the classic article "lambda, the ultimate goto" - it explains very well why recursive functions dont necessarily need to be less efficient than imperative loops.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's the normal way of doing it.

Comment: I have seen the two ways as a normal way of doing it :)

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically both your solution and the recursive solution have the same [Big Oh complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). In theory they are both O(log n). If you want performance measured in seconds you need to go practical, write the code of both methods (iterative, recursive), run them and measure the run time.